# Domain wont console log sent message

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Hello I'm trying to create a chat application, I googled around and I got some issues on this step. Would appreciate some help...

Server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var http = require("http").createServer(app);

var io =  require("socket.io")(http);

var users = [];

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    console.log("User connected", socket.id);

    socket.on("user_connected", function (username) {

        users[username] = socket.id;

        io.emit("user_connected", username);
    });

    socket.on("send_message", function (data) {
        var socketId = users[data];
        io.to(socketId).emit("new_message", data);
        console.log(data);
    });


});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server Started");
});
```

chat.php

```
function sendMessage(){
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
io.emit("send_message", {
    sender: sender,
    message: message
});
    return false;
}

io.on("new_message", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    //var html = "";
    //html += "<li>" + data.sender + " says: " + data.message + "</li>";
    //document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += html;
});
```

So my problem is happening in chat.php where my console.log(data) isn't shown, however the data is shown in server.js. Why is this currently not working?

Comment: What browser? Have you tried logging a string right before the data?

Comment: Google Chrome, didn't work either I'm afraid

Comment: Is there a receiver as given by `users[data.receiver]`? Also are you looking in the console where the receiver is connected?

Comment: It is possible that `"new_message"` event isn't fired, when you're expecting a log. So indirectly, I suspect if `function sendMessage` is called?

Comment: @RahulVerma when I log the sendMessage function I get the correct data of sender, receiver and message

Comment: @OluwafemiSule seems that you are on to something, receiver is not defined when i console log it

Comment: I removed the receiver value, but still gets the same issue, console log won't show

Comment: Seems like the variable socketId is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you said earlier it's possible that you make it more complicated than it actually is. No need to change anything in chat.php, however instead of creating the variable socketId you could just emit the data immediately like this:

```
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("User connected", socket.id);

  socket.on("user_connected", function (username) {

    users[username] = socket.id;

    io.emit("user_connected", username);
});

  socket.on("send_message", function (data) {
    io.emit("new_message", data);
  });

});
```

Comment: No worries, glad to help